# Inserting an existing photo from file

Tags: excel, vba, image, button

I want to add an image to a specific cell on active sheet. The image should fit the cell. I found a piece of code which works perfectly but I get an error message when the sheet is protected. I have to keep the sheet protected with the object editing unchecked before sharing the file with my coworkers.

How can I overcome this problem?

The code I use:

```
Sub AddPhoto()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objPic As Picture
    Dim rngDest As Range
    strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Images (*.jpg;*.gif;*.png),*.jpg;*.gif;*.png", _
        Title:="Please select an image...")
    If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Set rngDest = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A10:D20")
    Set objPic = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Pictures.Insert(strFileName)
    With objPic
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Left = rngDest.Left
        .Top = rngDest.Top
        .Width = rngDest.Width
        .Height = rngDest.Height
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[Unprotect](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.unprotect) at the start of your code, and re-[protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect) at the end.

One way or another, the destination range can't be protected if you want to put an image in it.
(That's what [protection](https://support.microsoft.com/office/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6) is protecting against.)

Comment: Acutally "A10:D20" range is a merged cell and it's not protected. But I will try your first suggestion, I belive it will work if I can make it.

Comment: It worked perfectly :) The solution was easier than I could imagine. Thank you so much

Comment: I just realized that when I share the file with others, the photos are not visible. Apparently, excel was adding the path of the photo to the sheet, not the photo itself. Need urgent help